# Using a function in replaced dom content

Tags: jquery, dom, slideshow, replacewith

Okay so heres the problem. I'm replacing html content with the jquery function replace.with. Some parts of the HTML contains an imageslider from the library http://responsiveslides.com/ except the Jquery that makes the slide functional doesnt fire after the content is replaced. On the initial page it works fine then after I replace the content it stops working. However i did get it working with adding a click event on the page with the replaced content.

```
$(document.on('click', '.title', function(){
$("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,
  speed: 500, 
  });
  });
```

so above code works fine, how ever I want it to fire when the content is replaced. Not when the user clicks on a button on the new page. I also tried this:

```
$(document).on('click','#title1', function(){
GoToFusion();
$("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
auto: true,
speed: 500,
});
});
```

And I also tried putting the folowing code in the HTML that is replacing the old HTML hoping it would just fire after the page loaded...

```
<script> $(function () {   
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "large-btns"
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Also I dont think theres anything wrong with the HTML or CSS, because the slider works fine with the click event.
My deadline for school is closing in and i really could use some help... Thanks!!

p.s. sorry for my bad english its not my native language.

edit:

```
//function GoToFusion()
function GoToFusion() {
$("#Box1_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box1_Index").replaceWith(Box1_Fusion);
});
$("#Box2_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box2_Index").replaceWith(Box2_Fusion);
});
$("#Box3_Index, #Box3_Contact").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500,       function () {
    $("#Box3_Index, #Box3_Contact").replaceWith(Box3_Fusion);
});
$("#Box4_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box4_Index").replaceWith(Box4_Fusion);
});       
}
```

Comment: What is the code that contains your `replaceWith()`?

Comment: Hi, i added the code of the function GoToFusion()  to the question. Box4_Fusion contains the html of the slider. I just tested the first code again seems to still work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you can't get that without re-initializing the plugin - which is something you're doing (kind of) with your "on-click" workaround. I'd suggest triggering a click event after you replace the content.

So if you have

```
$(document.on('click', '.title', function(){
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      speed: 500, 
    });
});
$("#Box1_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box1_Index").replaceWith(Box1_Fusion);
    $(document).trigger('click'); //trigger click on the document
});
```

To me this seems quite inefficient (costly) though. If the plugin supports reinit (or a form of autoupdate), i'd suggest just replacing the content inside the DOM the plugin uses.

Comment: Just tried this and it doesnt seem to work. When i click manually on the .title the slider starts working. Also ye this feel inefficient... I just checked the library again and couldnt find anything about an init or auto update function. Could you maybe explain to me why I can't just fire the code of the slider after i replaced the content. like this: haha as im typing this i found a sulution!!! check my question for the answer. Thanks man your suggestion gave me an idea !! appreciated!!

Comment: @HobieWetzels What i wrote did not work for you, because you included your animation inside the document click event (and it would go on and on and on). I took it as a separate thing for clarification. Good thing that you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#title1', function(){

$("#Box1_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box1_Index").replaceWith(Box1_Fusion);
});
$("#Box2_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box2_Index").replaceWith(Box2_Fusion);
});
$("#Box3_Index, #Box3_Contact").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box3_Index, #Box3_Contact").replaceWith(Box3_Fusion);
});
$("#Box4_Index").animate({ 'margin-left': '100%' }, 1500, function () {
    $("#Box4_Index").replaceWith(Box4_Fusion);
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "large-btns"
  });
});
```

Did the trick, maybe not the most efficient way, but it works for me. Thanks for helping me out!